# MongoDB Ruby Bounds Query without an ORM

Tags: ruby, mongodb, geospatial

I'm trying to figure out how to issue a bounding box geoquery to mongodb using the ruby driver without an ORM wrapper like Mongoid or MongoMapper.

I can execute near commands no problem but I can't seem to figure out the syntax for a find with a within.

So this Works like a charm if I want to query within a radius

```
conn = Mongo::Connection.from_uri('my DB')
  db = conn.db('my_sites')
  coll = db.command({'geoNear' => "sites",
             'near'=>[lng,lat],
             'spherical' => true,
             'maxDistance' => distance_in_radians,
             'num' => limit})
  render :json => coll['results'].to_a
```

But I'm stumped on getting the query right for a within:

```
box = [[34.05,-118.24],[35.80,116.44]]
coll = db.command({'within' => "sites", 'box' => box}
```

or

```
db['my_sites']
coll = db.find({"box" => box})
```

I can issue queries directly in the mongo client but I'm just tripped up understanding the ruby driver syntax.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the MongoDB shell version would look like this:

```
db.my_sites.find(loc: { $within: { $box: box } })
```

The low-level Ruby interface generally mirrors the JavaScript interface so I think you want:

```
db['my_sites'].find(:loc => { :$within => { :$box => box } })
```

I don't have a geo-ready collection handy so I can't test it to make sure.